# Javascript multiple elements toggle got unexpected results

Tags: javascript, django, forms, toggle

I'm working on a project in Django, where on each page I have comments, generated automatically from the database. For each of them I want to have **a form in which someone can reply to those comments**. **I do not want the form to be visible all the time**, but **only when the reply button is pressed**.

I tried to use **getElementsByClassName**, but when I pressed the button, the visible forms disappeared and the hidden ones appeared. I then tried to use **getElementById**, and **called the function with the comment id**. The result was that, whatever button I pressed, only the last comment's form appeared and disappeared, the others remaining unchanged. The variable only keeps the last element's id. When using this code, I inspected the result and the ids are the right ones.

**I would like to see only the form for which the button is pressed.**

This is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
                          var x = document.getElementById({{ comment.id }});
                              if (x.style.display === "none") {
                                x.style.display = "block";
                              } else {
                                x.style.display = "none";
                              }
                        }
```

```html
{% for comment in comments %}
  <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="myFunction({{ comment.id }})">Reply</button>
  <div id="{{ comment.id }}">
      <form method="post">
          {{ comment_form.as_p }}
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">
          <input class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" value="Reply">
      </form>
      <hr>
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: In `onclick` you are passing a value(?) and in the function, you are not "collecting" it.  
You have: `myFunction()` instead of something like: `myFunction(somedata)`.

Comment: It works! I was not passing by the parameter! Thank you! The only change i made was to us this: function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);